# How to get sitelink extension metrics with the new google ads api V10

Tags: c#, google-ads-api

I need help with getting metrics for sitelink extensions. I have tried this query but no results are returned. I can see 6 sitelink extensions in the UI.

SELECT campaign.name, feed_item.attribute_values, metrics.clicks, metrics.impressions, metrics.ctr , segments.interaction_on_this_extension, segments.placeholder_type FROM feed_item WHERE  segments.date BETWEEN '2022-04-10' AND '2022-05-10' ORDER BY metrics.clicks DESC LIMIT 10

Answer (score 0):

The sitelinks in the Ads account you are querying might have [been migrated](https://ads-developers.googleblog.com/2022/01/revised-schedule-for-auto-migration-of.html) to [Asset-based extensions](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/extensions/assets/asset-extensions). Any metrics collected after the migration will be attributed to the assets, not the feed items. You could try setting the date range of your query further back into the past to confirm that hypothesis.

There doesn't seem to be a report type that would allow you to both get assets' attribute and corresponding metrics at the same time, so it looks like you'll have to use a combination of the [`asset_field_type_view`](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v10/asset_field_type_view) and [`asset`](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v10/asset) resources to get all of the data you require.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I realized after further reading. You can get asset attributes and metrics using campaign_ / customer_ / adgroup_ assets

Comment: True, that's a better way of getting metrics.[`campaign_asset`](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v10/campaign_asset) seems to be even closer to your original query.